# The argument type 'Void Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Void Function(BuildContext, Meal)'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and got this error. this app has 3 screens so far and I have a problem with some widgets. here is the overview image of my project in VisualStioCode.
[Overview of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVjSy.png)

here is the full code of meals. dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:meals/models/meal.dart';
import 'package:meals/screens/meal_details.dart';
import 'package:meals/widgets/meal_item.dart';

class MealsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MealsScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.meals,
  });

  final String title;
  final List<Meal> meals;

  void selectMeal(BuildContext context, Meal meal) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => MealDetailsScreen(
          meal: meal,
        ),
      ),
    ); // Navigator.push(context, route);
  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget content = Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Uh oh ... nothing here! ',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge!.copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          Text(
            'Try selecting a different category!',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    if (meals.isNotEmpty) {
      content = ListView.builder(
        itemCount: meals.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MealItem(
          meal: meals[index],
          onSelectMeal: (meal) {
            selectMeal(context , meal);
          },
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: content,
    );
  }
}
```

and also I have an error in my meal_item.dart file. here is the error:

> The argument type 'Meal' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.

here is the Screenshot of error:[meal_dart error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RE0I.png)

here is my meal_item.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meals/widgets/meal_item_trait.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

import 'package:meals/models/meal.dart';

class MealItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MealItem({
    super.key,
    required this.meal,
    required this.onSelectMeal,
  });

  final Meal meal;
  final void Function(BuildContext context, Meal meal) onSelectMeal;

  String get complexityText {
    return meal.complexity.name[0].toUpperCase() +
        meal.complexity.name.substring(1);
  }

  String get affordablitiyText {
    return meal.affordability.name[0].toUpperCase() +
        meal.affordability.name.substring(1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      elevation: 2,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          onSelectMeal(meal);
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            FadeInImage(
              placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
              image: NetworkImage(meal.imageUrl),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black54,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 6,
                  horizontal: 44,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      meal.title,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      softWrap: true,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Very long text ...
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 12),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        MealItemTrait(
                          icon: Icons.schedule,
                          label: '${meal.duration} min',
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 12),
                        MealItemTrait(
                          icon: Icons.work,
                          label: complexityText,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 12),
                        MealItemTrait(
                          icon: Icons.attach_money,
                          label: affordablitiyText,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `MealItem` declares its `onSelectMeal` member to be a function callback that takes a `BuildContext` and a `Meal` as arguments.  However, when you initialize `onSelectMeal`, you pass a function that accepts only a `Meal` argument.    Just initialize `onSelectMeal: selectMeal`.  Furthermore, when you try to invoke it, you pass only a `meal` argument.  Instead, you shoudl be calling `onSelectMeal(context, meal)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is due to the way you use to call OnSelectMeal, funcation in your MealItem. To fix it use this code -

```
onTap: () {
  onSelectMeal(context, meal); // add context and meal as arguments
},
```

i hope this works well, if you face any problem please let me know